# javascript click event onload page href whatsapp

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, whatsapp

I am having anchor tag in my page. I like to trigger click event `onload` . Which means I wanna open this link `"whatsapp://send?text=test&phone=+123456789"` go to whatsapp. The link is working if you manually click, but not working onload page.  Same result with jquery. Is there anyway to do this?

This is what I have:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('openwhatsapp').click();">
    <a id="openwhatsapp" href="whatsapp://send?text=test&phone=+123456789">whatsapp</a>
</body>
```

To clarify this, there is no problem for the link with `http://`, its working. Just not working for `whatsapp://` maybe?

Comment: any other ways to solve this guys?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't use inline JS. It's just not right.

Now coming to the solution. Why don't you try something like

```
document.body.onload = function(){
     window.location.href = "whatsapp://send?text=test&phone=+123456789";
}
```

If you still want to stick to inline JS, I'd suggest prefix your code with `javascript:` since some browsers otherwise ignore inline JS.

So now your code would become

```
<body onload="javascript:document.getElementById('openwhatsapp').click();">
    <a id="openwhatsapp" href="whatsapp://send?text=test&phone=+123456789">whatsapp</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Please elaborate a little more. Is the URL correct? Is the console showing any errors? Because I tried the code and it's working

Comment: what do mean working? is it onclick or onload? as i tested its only clicking the url is working, while onload nothing happen.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `location.href` is a good solution for you.

```
<body onload="location.href = 'whatsapp://send?text=test&phone=+60123456789">
     <a id="openwhatsapp" href="whatsapp://send?text=test&phone=+60123456789">whatsapp</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
<href="intent://send/0123456789#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end">
```

what is happening when u click on the link ? any error or blank page ?

Comment: also tried this one, not working onload, manually click working

Answer (score 0):

You can use, `$(window).load(function() {})` or even `$(document).ready(function() {})`

```
$(window).load(function() {
  location.href = 'whatsapp://send?text=test&phone=+60123456789'
});
```

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  location.href = 'whatsapp://send?text=test&phone=+60123456789'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="openwhatsapp" href="whatsapp://send?text=test&phone=+60123456789">whatsapp</a>
```

**Run this snippet, it is working**

Comment: which browser you are using, its working fine in chrome in ubuntu.

Comment: using phone samsung, asus and chrome browser

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it on load then why you are not using :

```
window.location = "whatsapp://send?text=test&phone=+123456789"
```